# List files and files of subdirectories from a given folder

Tags: java, file

I try to list all the files from a folder and its subdirectories to be uploaded one by one. It couldn't list files from subfolders of folder, just uses files from same folder multiple times.

```
    int num=1;
    public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName) throws InterruptedException {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(fList);
        String filestatus;


        for (File file : fList){
            if (file.isFile() && !(file.getName().contains("nfo"))){
                int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf("_");
                if(index <= 0){
                    filestatus="INVALID";
                }else{
                    filestatus = file.getName().substring(0, index);
                }
            } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getParent());
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this line be: `listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getPath());` ?

Comment: If the file is directory you should call recursively on that object not on its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getParent());
```

with:

```
listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "Tree" :

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode listFile(File file, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){

int count = 0;      

if(file.isFile())

  return new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());

else{

  File[] list = file.listFiles();

  if(list == null)

    return new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());


  for(File nom : list){

    count++;

    //not more than 5 childs node

    if(count < 5){

      DefaultMutableTreeNode subNode;

      if(nom.isDirectory()){

        subNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nom.getName()+"\\");

        node.add(this.listFile(nom, subNode));

      }else{

        subNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nom.getName());

      }

      node.add(subNode);

    }

  }

  return node;

}
```

}

see more [here](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/26832-apprenez-a-programmer-en-java/25154-les-arbres-et-leur-structure)
The doc is in french but you may find what you need.